# Linq Contains: Performance on list vs array

Tags: contains

In my program I have an array of integers (`int[]`). Later I need to add more integers to the list. That is why I convert the array to a `List<int>`. I was wondering on which `Enumerable` I should apply the [Contains](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb352880(v=vs.110).aspx) calls I require.

It is small lists I am talking about and only a couple of searches. Converting to a `HashSet` would be too much overhead.

In theory finding a specific item in a list as well as an array has complexity O(n). On average n/2 items need to be iterated and checked before finding the wanted one.

I was curious whether in practice this theory holds, too. So my question is: For small data sets, is there a noticable performance difference between `List<int>.Contains()` and `int[].Contains()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a test method showing:

**There is no measurable difference between both when using random data.**

Here the test code which uses a random generator to insert and calls `Contains` on random data for a `List`. Then the random generator is reset and the same sequences are inserted and then queried on an array.

```
var seedGenerator = new Random();
const int RunsPerRound = 10;
int[] itemsPerRound = { 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 100, 1000, 2000, 3000, 4000, 5000, 10000, 20000 };
foreach (var items in itemsPerRound)
{
    var runsPerRound = RunsPerRound;
    // For very small test sets, increase number of runs
    if (items < 100)
        runsPerRound = 1000;
    int totalRoundItems = items * runsPerRound;
    long totalRoundTicksList = 0;
    long totalRoundTicksArray = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < runsPerRound; i++)
    {
        // List
        int seed = seedGenerator.Next();
        var r = new Random(seed);
        var list = new List<int>(items);
        for (int j = 0; j < items; j++)
            list.Add(r.Next());
        var sw = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();
        sw.Start();
        for (int j = 0; j < items; j++)
            list.Contains(r.Next());
        sw.Stop();
        totalRoundTicksList += sw.ElapsedTicks;

        // Array
        r = new Random(seed);
        var array = new int[items];
        for (int j = 0; j < items; j++)
            array[j] = r.Next();
        sw.Reset();
        sw.Start();
        for (int j = 0; j < items; j++)
            list.Contains(r.Next());
        sw.Stop();
        totalRoundTicksArray += sw.ElapsedTicks;
    }

    double perItemTicksList = totalRoundTicksList / totalRoundItems;
    double perItemTicksArray = totalRoundTicksArray / totalRoundItems;
    double ticksRatio = (double)totalRoundTicksList / totalRoundTicksArray;
    Console.WriteLine($"ItemsPerRound {items}:\tList:{totalRoundTicksList}\tArray:{totalRoundTicksArray}\tRatio:{ticksRatio:0.###}\tListPerItem:{perItemTicksList}\tArrayPerItem:{perItemTicksArray}");
}
```

On my machine I get these results. Note that the ratio between the time for `Contains` on `List` vs. array is very close to 1.

```
ItemsPerRound 10:       List:1576       Array:1373      Ratio:1.148     ListPerItem:0   ArrayPerItem:0
ItemsPerRound 20:       List:3640       Array:4203      Ratio:0.866     ListPerItem:0   ArrayPerItem:0
ItemsPerRound 30:       List:7617       Array:7652      Ratio:0.995     ListPerItem:0   ArrayPerItem:0
ItemsPerRound 40:       List:12675      Array:12565     Ratio:1.009     ListPerItem:0   ArrayPerItem:0
ItemsPerRound 50:       List:19381      Array:19098     Ratio:1.015     ListPerItem:0   ArrayPerItem:0
ItemsPerRound 100:      List:664        Array:616       Ratio:1.078     ListPerItem:0   ArrayPerItem:0
ItemsPerRound 1000:     List:57581      Array:56698     Ratio:1.016     ListPerItem:5   ArrayPerItem:5
ItemsPerRound 2000:     List:239500     Array:259884    Ratio:0.922     ListPerItem:11  ArrayPerItem:12
ItemsPerRound 3000:     List:547807     Array:526768    Ratio:1.04      ListPerItem:18  ArrayPerItem:17
ItemsPerRound 4000:     List:1059016    Array:1023493   Ratio:1.035     ListPerItem:26  ArrayPerItem:25
ItemsPerRound 5000:     List:1402850    Array:1385418   Ratio:1.013     ListPerItem:28  ArrayPerItem:27
ItemsPerRound 10000:    List:5814664    Array:5888034   Ratio:0.988     ListPerItem:58  ArrayPerItem:58
ItemsPerRound 20000:    List:22417904   Array:22015204  Ratio:1.018     ListPerItem:112 ArrayPerItem:110
```